# Diagonalizing an unitary matrix with numpy doesn't yield orthonormal eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to diagonalize an unitary matrix using numpy, in particular the `numpy.linalg.eig` function. Since the matrix is unitary, its eigenvectors are supposed to form an orthonormal basis. However, it seems that this is not the case:

```py
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

op = Operator(QFT(num_qubits=4, do_swaps=True)).data
eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(op) # Compute the eigenvalues
eigvecs = eigvecs.T # Since the eigenvectors are arranged in columns
lambda_i = eigvals[2]
lambda_j = eigvals[-1]
v_i = eigvecs[2].reshape((-1, 1))
v_j = eigvecs[-1].reshape((-1, 1))
print(np.linalg.norm(op @ v_i - lambda_i * v_i)) # Should be close to 0 by definition, actually yields 6.706985734026871e-16, which is fine
print(np.linalg.norm(op @ v_j - lambda_j * v_j)) # Should be close to 0 by definition, actually yields 8.151878100248519e-16, which is fine
print(v_j.T.conj() @ v_i) # Should be close to zero since the basis is supposed to be orthonormal but actually yields array([[-0.15147621-0.06735767j]]), which is not fine
print(np.linalg.norm(op.T.conj() @ op - np.eye(16))) # Should be around zero if and only if op.data is unitary, actually yields 2.3337334181537826e-15, which is ine
```

I've tested it with the qiskit library, however my question is purely numpy-related. If required, the same matrix can be loaded using the following .npy file:

```
b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '<c16', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (16, 16), }                                                       \n\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?`\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?A\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf`\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfA\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?D\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf[\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?Z\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfD\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?[\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfZ\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?d\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf]\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfd\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?A\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfd\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?]\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?d\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfA\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfZ\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfD\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbfd\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?Y\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?Z\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?D\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?d\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfY\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf`\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?A\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?`\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfA\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?D\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?[\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?Z\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfD\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf[\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfZ\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfd\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?]\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfd\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfA\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00^\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?d\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf]\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?d\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?A\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?c\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfZ\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?D\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\x05\\\x143&\xa6q\xbc\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbfd\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbfC\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfY\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbf\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd\xbfc\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?\xca;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6\xbf\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?Z\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8\xbfD\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\x05\\\x143&\xa6q<\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xcf?d\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?\xcb;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?\xc9;\x7ff\x9e\xa0\xc6?C\x8d2\xcfk\x90\xcd?Y\xa9\xae\xa6\xe2}\xb8?"
```

The behavior seems to occur only for purely complex (that is, with a nil real part) eigenvalues. For most of the other eigenvectors, the scalar product does yield 0, but I was able to remplicate this behavior on others.

I don't think it is due to some numerical approximation since the final scalar product is quite large.

I don't think it is due to some conjugation that I would have forgot. As a sanity check, I've ensured that `v_i` and `v_j` are indeed eigenvectors of `op`, which means they are correct, and which means they should be orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the reasoning comes from this part:

> As a sanity check, I've ensured that v_i and v_j are indeed eigenvectors of op, which means they are correct, and which means they should be orthogonal.

If v_i and v_j are associated to the same eigenvalue lambda, then (v_i+v_j)/sqrt(2) is an eigenvector associated to lambda and which isn't orthogonal to v_i or v_j.

In order to ensure that the eigenvectors are orthogonal, simply perform:

```py
eigvecs = np.linalg.qr(eigvecs)[0]
```

`eigvecs` will now contain orthonormal eigenvectors of `op`.